# XBBG works for some indexes, but not others

Tags: python, finance, bloomberg, blpapi

I've been using `xbbg` to get historical data for some indexes, and while some work no problem, others will return an empty dataframe.

Here's an example version of the kind of code I've been using:

```
from xbbg import blp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
xbbgdf = blp.bdh(
    tickers=['JPEIDIVR Index','JCMDCOMP Index', 'JGENVUUG Index'], flds=['px_last'],
    start_date='2018-06-30', end_date='2018-11-30',
    Per = "M"
    )
```

This returns a dataframe containing only the data for JEPIDIVR.

What are some steps I can take to make sure I can pull these historical data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the other of the tickers you ask for? If you switch them around does it return the first value in the list or does it still return JPEIDIVR?

Comment: Good question. It still returns just JPEIDIVR. Additionally, I tried adding in another index, SPX, and it returned JPEIDIVR and SPX.

Comment: Is it possible that JCMDCOMP and JGENVUUG do not have historical data for the dates you specified? Maybe try more recent dates to test this theory.

Comment: Just tried this, still no luck. FWIW, I tried this in an excel sheet, and they were returned without a problem. Unfortunately, I really can't use excel for this project.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it work if you use GBIE1545 as your ticker instead of JGENVUUG?

Comment: Nice, that was successful! How did you find that alternate name?

Additionally, I just noticed that when I put JGENVUUG into the Bloomberg terminal, it says "access to this security is restricted by its supplier", do you thing this could have something to do with my issue?

Comment: I do not know if Bloomberg has tiers of data access where some historical security data is only available to certain users, but that is possible. Please verify that the security data is correct for the ticker I gave you. I think it is correct but am not certain.

Comment: Good call to check, I guess they're not the same, but it looks like they to have this kind of thing, I'm talking to them right now. Thank you very much for your help!